# Should I use a friend class here?

Tags: c++, class, friend

I'm just getting back into C++ with a friend of mine. I'm writing a basic text based dungeon game, trying to get the player to move up, down, left and right. Well my question has two parts.

I created a Map class, a Player class and a GameLoop class. Everything that happens is obviously going inside my GameLoop. The Map class has a function called Move() to move the player. In the Map class, should I let my Player class have friendship access to the Map class? I'm a little confused with when to use friend classes. I'm wondering whether the game loop function should use map.Move(), or if i should place Move() into the Player class, make them friends, and use player.Move().

My **Map class** holds the private data of the coordinates, which are where my player is positioned.

I know this might be a little subjective but I'm kinda talking in general. Is using a friend class more efficient then using the Map object directly?

On to my second question. I know that classes are very common, but I'm wondering if objects are. Should at least one object be created for every class, or could you even create a class and use it without making an object?

Comment: Why did you choose to make `Move()` a member function of `Map`, rather than `Player`?

Comment: @Maxpm: there are many reasons to do this, one of which is that `Map` encapsulates the player's location.  This is really useful when you're doing collision detection on a 2D grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Classes are useful because they can have methods and state/data**. Generally speaking, if there is any data in your class, it's meaningless that you don't create any objects. However,
you can implement a utility class which is composed of public static functions only. In such a case you don't have to create any object.

```
Class CMyHelper
{
public:
    static double calculateDistance(CPoint A, CPoint B);
    static double calculateArea(double length, double width);
    //...
private:
    // You can even explictly say, I don't want make objects of this class.
    // You'll get a compile-time error if someone tries.
    CMyHelper();
    CMyHelper(const CMyHelper&);
}

CPoint A(100, 200);
CPoint B(50, 100);
//Call static method without instantiation
CMyHelper::calculateDistance(A, B);
```

**In your case, there is no need to use static class, and friend class as we can see.**

To me, friend class is the last thing I'll resort to. According to your description, you can make `move()` be the public method of `player` class since it's the player who actually "moves" instead of the `map`. Also, you need make it clear to us what's your `map` class does.

**Edit:**  You can move coordinate of the player to player class if your map class is simpe enough to remove.

```
Class CPlayer
{
public:
    void move()
    {
        // moves up, down, left, or right
        // update m_position
    }
}

private:
    CCoordinate m_position;
}
```

Comment: You can create a class and use it without "making objects" of it.  These are called static classes in case you wanted to look into it a bit further.

Comment: I see. So I should usually just use objects of the classes I create, even though in this example map.Move() makes less sense than player.Move()? I need Move() to access Map either way because the coordinates of the player are private data of Map. And thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, please use objects for your preference since in your case there isn't any need for a static class as I can see. You can make a map object part of your player's state so that in your player's move(), you can access coordinates. Again, what's inside map other than corrdinates? If nothing else, you can move it into player class and get rid of map...

Comment: Well, there really isn't much else in Map. I've only been working on this for a few hours and its mainly a practice project for me to get used to creating and using classes agian.

Answer (score 2):

Being `friends` is the tightest coupling two classes can have. In general, you want to avoid the dependencies implied in high coupling. Have your `Player` class use the public interface of the `Map` class, unless you absolutely *have* to use `friend`.

I would do something like this:

```
void MainLoop() {
    // ... Read input and so on ...

    player.Move(input);
    map.Update(player.GetPosition());
}
```

Regarding efficiency: `friend` does not really relate to efficiency, since the public/protected/private checks are applied at compile-time. And even if it did, using `friend` to achieve efficiency would be a star example of premature optimization -- which you should avoid.

If your class has some or only static members, it could be used without instantiating an object. A more common case where you have a class but no members are abstract interfaces. These classes are designed to be base classes defining an interface, which later classes then inherit and implement.

Comment: I didn't know you could pass a function as a parameter.?

Comment: @vorbis5: You can pass function pointers, functors (and in C++0x, lambdas). However, in the code above `input` is supposed to be a regular variable, and `player.GetPosition()` is not a function, it's the function's return value.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the answer is subjective, I would prefer keeping `Move()` inside `player` class, as it is performing an action on the `Player`.

I am not sure of what `Map` class is supposed to do. You didn't mention a detail on that.

***Could you even create a class and use it without making an object?***
Yes, It is possible to have a class and have static methods inside the class which can then be called without even creating an object of the class. I cannot think of an practical example  though.

An code example:

```
class MyClass
{
    static int i;

    public:
    static void incrementCount()
    {
         i++;
    }

    static int returnCount()
    {
         return i;
    }
};

int MyClass::i = 0;

int main()
{

    int count;
    //Do Some processing

    MyClass::incrementCount();

    //Do Some More processing

    count = MyClass::returnCount();        

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use Map because it holds the coordinates of the player in its private data.

Comment: @vorbis5: You can call public method exposed by Map to update the Map with details of the move.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to react to the two general aspects of your question, and sort of avoid the special case you're referring to.  You haven't provided much detail, and I hope the general case will help you decide whether you need use friendship or not.

> I'm a little confused with when to use friend classes.

`friend` is more like `protected` than `public` or `private` in that it grants *partial* or *selective* access.  You usually need to use a `friend` declaration when you specifically want to grant access to a single class or function, rather than grant access to anybody.

You're in a rock and a hard place: you *must* grant access, so you can't use `private`; then again you *must* encapsulate your data, so you can't use `public`.  In those cases,  `friend` and `protected` allow you to squeeze out of that tight spot.

The basic difference between `friend` and `protected` is that the latter is *open ended* in the number of entities to whom you grant access.

If you want more details or examples, the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) has a [great section about friends](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html).

> I know this might be a little subjective but I'm kinda talking in general. Is using a friend class more efficient then using the Map object directly?

This has nothing to do with being subjective.  Access restrictions are only used during compilation, not at program run-time.  Therefore, they incur no runtime overhead.  If the referred data member is accessed through a simple inlined getter function, then that shouldn't incur overhead either.  In any case, I wouldn't start investigating this untlil I had ruled out a bunch of other cases, as this is likely *not* your bottleneck.